# Add Navigation Property Manually to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, navigation-properties

I need to add a navigation property between two Entities TableA and TableB

**TableA**

```
ID : Primary Key 

Code: String (Allows Null)
```

**TableB**

```
BID:  Primary Key

Code: String (Allows Null)
```

Now I want to add a navigation property to these Entities which are related by the code which is not a foreign key. Can anyone tell me how this is possible

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not possible because code is not PK in any of your tables. Navigation properties follows same rules as database relations - in principal table you must use PK and in dependent you specify FK. Databases also offers selecting unique key in principal table but EF doesn't support unique keys yet.